# Is there a plug-in for Joomla that will auto-generate content from SVN?

Tags: svn, joomla

I am considering Joomla for use on our intranet and I was wondering if there was a plug-in for it that would allow pages to auto-generate content from SVN files like Word documents. We have a number of processes and working practices in documents controlled by SVN and rather than move each one to a different format, I'd rather have them directly imported. Also, that way, we don't need to update the Joomla site every time a file changes in SVN.

So, is there any way to do this?

I have looked around but all I find is how to control Joomla site development using SVN, rather than how to link Joomla pages to auto-generate content from files under control in SVN.

I apologise if this question is somewhat naive, this is not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up post-commit hooks in SVN to run a script to export the relevant documents to the website server. That way, updating a word document will automatically export that document to the correct place. I'd use export rather than a checkout onto the webserver so you don't get .svn directories on the server. However, you can turn off apache processing for .svn directories, and if you did this, you'd be able to update the server just by calling "svn update" on the site's root directory.

Of course, this requires the documents be stored on the filesystem, not imported into the Joomla db.

Answer (score 1):

This search, http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search/svn, seems to indicate there are none in the 'known/official' repository.

Shame - this sounds like it'd be really useful, too :)

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-submission/6260 is sorta close, but it's versioning *inside* Joomla itself.