# Is there a CMS that supports auto-generated content from SVN controlled files?

Tags: svn, intranet, content-management

We are looking to update our intranet with a content management system that provides wiki and forum support, as well as (hopefully) support for auto-generating content from files controlled under SVN such as Word documents. The aim is that we don't need to update the intranet each time a working practise changes and that we don't need to change the format of all our existing procedures to something more web-friendly.

I have already [asked a question more specific to a particular CMS](https://serverfault.com/questions/46474/is-there-a-plug-in-for-joomla-that-will-auto-generate-content-from-svn) with no answers so far, but what I'd like to know is whether there is ANY CMS out there that can achieve what we'd like, free or otherwise?

Comment: So you don't really need any SVN support, you just want to make the contents of the directory available via the web.  Do you want it published as articles?  Browseable directories?

Comment: I meant to put a ? at the beginning of the first sentence.

Comment: I want to make sure that the latest revision of a document has a representation within the system without any intervention whatsoever.

Comment: (other than updating the SVN repository from somewhere)

Answer (score 2):

Drupal has a Version Control module with Subversion support. You could use that API to hook into your SVN install.

Yeah, it'd involve some custom coding, but I think that's going to be the case for any CMS - your needs are pretty specialised.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, can you enable anonymous read access to the SVN repository over HTTP, and then write a wrapper to do a nice representation of it in the browser?

I know this isn't a CMS, but you could probably write a plugin for a CMS to do this...

Comment: Writing a plug-in is certainly within the realms of possibility on this.

Answer (score 1):

So you want an intranet which only displays the most recent version of a certain document? That sounds like document management, [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) could be something to consider. As a coder I find using subversion for document management a bad practise...

You can use [Alfresco Share](http://www.alfresco.com/products/collaboration/) to have some collaboration features (like a wiki), or if your needs are more elaborate you could integrate Alfresco with [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I'd just use the CMS to link to the word document in a working copy somewhere (on the web/cms server I suppose) - because, does it really have to generate content *from* the word document?

Then a commit hook in svn that does an update on that working copy when it changes (or just a scheduled update for the really easy-to-do approach) - voila all linked word documents are always on the latest revision (with whatever delay you could expect).

Answer (score 0):

not CMS but rather Trac Project http://trac.edgewall.org/, may not be what you looking for exactly I just wanted to let people know (whoever isn't familiar with this great product), it integrates with SVN very well.